# Is there any solution of symbol lookup error that is produced because of -allow-shlib-undefined linker switch?

Tags: c, linker

I am trying to understand to usage of "-allow-shlib-undefined" switch of gnu linker.
For this purpose, I wrote libfoo.so and libfunc.so.

```
//libfoo.h
void say_hello(void);
```

```
//libfoo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libfoo.h"
#include "libfunc.h"

void say_hello(void)
{
   printf("Hello\n");
   say_goodbye();
}
```

```
//libfunc.h
void say_goodbye(void);
```

```
//libfunc.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libfunc.h"

void say_goodbye(void)
{
    printf("Goodbye!\n");
}
```

And I compile libfoo and libfunc with using following gcc commands:

```
gcc -c libfoo.c -o libfoo.o
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so libfoo.o

gcc -c libfunc.c -o libfunc.o
gcc -shared -o libfunc.so libfunc.o
```

Then I wrote following "main" code:

```
#include "libfoo.h"
int main(void) {
    say_hello();
}
```

Then I tried to compile this code with following gcc command:

```
gcc -L<path-to-libs> main.c -o main -lfoo
```

Error occurs with this command as I expected.(Because I didn't link libfunc.so)
Then I compile main.c with following gcc command:

```
gcc -L<path-to-libs> -Wl,-allow-shlib-undefined main.c -o main -lfoo
```

Compilation was succesfull with this command. but when I run main I get following error:

```
Hello
./main: symbol lookup error: /home/sarslan/shlib-undefined/libfoo.so: undefined symbol: say_goodbye
```

Is there any way to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to solve this error ?

Yes: the flag is *intended* for a situation where you *know* that the missing function will be provided *at runtime*, but (for whatever reason) you can't provide its definition *at link time*.

To make your program work, you must provide a *different* `libfoo.so` at runtime; one that *either*

1. doesn't call `say_goodby()`, or
2. provides its own definition of `say_goodby()`.

Alternatively, you can fix the runtime error by using `LD_PRELOAD=./libfunc.so`.

Beware: using `LD_PRELOAD` has many potential complications, and is almost never the right solution.

P.S. You are building your shared libraries without `-fPIC`. This wouldn't work on many architectures, and is suboptimal on systems where it does work.